# Manually add format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The specified value "March 12, 1993" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"

I'm trying to get the date and edit it on `@Html.EditorFor` but it doesn.t display the date
How to correctly format the date for `@Html.EditorFor`?

Model:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

View:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:206px;" } })
```

I tried using `"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` but it didn't work too.

Comment: Its `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` in the attribute, and just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { .... } })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke but I want it to display as `"{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}"` and be able to get the date and display it on @editfor.

Comment: The start by removing both your attributes (your generating the browsers HTML-5 datepicker - supported only in Chrome and Edge), and use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.DateOfBirth, "{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", new { .... })`, and then of corse you will need to write a custom `ModelBinder` to bind it when you post